# Can I Audit the SQL Server Audit?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was searching about SQL Server Audit (Server and Database Level). I was wondering if I can record if a Server or Database Level Audit changed (enable, disable, edit, delete).

I used **AUDIT_CHANGE_GROUP** action type. But it noticed that for server audit level it only records when it stops and not when it starts.

Is there any action type for what I want?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not possible to track actions on/changes of an Audit.

From the documentation, [SQL Server Audit Action Groups and Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions):

The following actions are intrinsically audited:

> Server Audit State Change (setting State to ON or OFF)

The following events are **not** intrinsically audited:

> CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION
>
> ALTER SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION
>
> DROP SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION
>
> CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION
>
> ALTER DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION
>
> DROP DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION

From the profiler's [Audit Change Audit Event Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/audit-change-audit-event-class) Data Columns

> EventSubClass:
>
> 1=Audit started
>
> 2=Audit stopped
>
> 3=C2 mode ON
>
> 4=C2 mode OFF

and for the extended events:

The SecAudit package is used by SQL Server Audit. None of the objects in the package are available through the Extended Events data definition language (DDL).